# How to make integration tests run using failsafe after docker-compose up is done?

Tags: java, docker, maven

I am using `mvn failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify` in order to run my integration tests. Every time I want to run them I have to do docker-compose up and manually check if docker is done so I can run the command

I was wondering if it's possible to tell maven to wait for the docker to complete bringing everything up so that I don't have to look at the logs manually? It would save a lot of time. Thanks!

(note: I have different images for different apps, so they can't be up all the time, aka. I have to do docker-compose up every time I want to run my integration tests).

Comment: another option is to run the whole test in test containers. which will automatically wait after all containers are up then test is executed

Comment: First it is wrong to call the goals manually instead of using the lifecycle via `mvn clean verify` .. If you have a docker-compose needed for your tests you should really take a deep look into https://testcontainers.org which really helps a lot here to handle things like ...

Answer (score 0):

You should have provide some application readiness service and wait for it using maven-antrun-plugin and ant's waitfor task; as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wait-on-service-availability</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <waitfor maxwait="30" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="1" checkeveryunit="second">
                        <http url="http://localhost:8080/status/ready"/>
                    </waitfor>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```